# Powershell textBox using watermark

Tags: powershell

I created some code here to do watermark but it's not working. I need to know the function and ways of how to control watermark. I'm trying to create a form with watermark.

We are only beginners in terms of powershell.

```
$TextBox1                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox1.multiline              = $false
$TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
$TextBox1.width                  = 100
$TextBox1.height                 = 20
$TextBox1.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(141,170)
$TextBox1.Font                   = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$WatermarkText = 'Enter Username'
$TextBox1.ForeColor = 'LightGray'
$TextBox1.Text = $WatermarkText

$TextBox1_Enter={
if($TextBox1.Text -eq $WatermarkText)
{
    #Clear the text
   $TextBox1.Text = ""
   $TextBox1.ForeColor = 'WindowText'
}
}

$TextBox1_Leave={
if($TextBox1.Text -eq "")
{
    #Display the watermark
    $TextBox1.Text = $WatermarkText
    $TextBox1.ForeColor = 'LightGray'
}
}


$TextBox1_VisibleChanged={
if($TextBox1.Visible -and $TextBox1.Tag -eq $null)
{
    #Initialize the watermark and save it in the Tag property
    $TextBox1.Tag = $TextBox1.Text;
    $TextBox1.ForeColor = 'LightGray'
    #If we have focus then clear out the text
    if($TextBox1.Focused)
    {
        $TextBox1.Text = ""
        $TextBox1.ForeColor = 'WindowText'
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your question is quite vague... you need to explain _how/why_ it's not working, what the expected function is (if it worked) and include any error messages. I would recommend reading [ask] and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). These will help you figure out what your question is missing so you can update your question and get an answer that will help you.

Answer (score 2):

The scriptblocks you have are just assigned to variables, not registered as event handlers on the `$TextBox` object.

Use something like `$TextBox.Add_Enter( {#your code  })`

instead of `$TextBox_Enter={#your code }`